# Naturality for the exponential map for pseudo-Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

[image]

Here $(M,g)$, $(\tilde M,\tilde g)$ consists of a smooth manifold $M$ (resp. $\tilde M$) with Riemannian metric $g$ (resp. $\tilde g$).

Does the result above hold for pseudo-Riemannian manifolds as well? Or more specifically, say we have $M=\mathbb R^4$, and $g$ is the Lorentz metric induced by
$$
\beta\colon\mathbb R^4\times\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R\colon (x,y)\mapsto x_1y_1-x_2y_2-x_3y_3-x_4y_4.
$$
Would Prop. 5.9 then hold still?

Comment: If you look at the 2nd edition of that book, all the theorems including that one is stated for riemann and the pseudo-riemann manifold if possible.

Comment: Hero! Thanks :-)